# Multiple text exchange in all files in a folder

Tags: text-processing

I want to search all files in a folder to this text

`$pw = 'my_password'`

If

`$pw = 'my_password'`

is included in the file, I want this through

`$pw = $new_pw`'

substitute

also, I would like if

`$pw = 'my_password'`

contained in the file, in the same file

`<?php`

through

`<?php`

`include('passwords.php');`

substitute.

**Important:** There must be a line break after `<?php`.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this ...

```
grep -li "\$pw = 'my_password'" *.php | xargs -I{} sed -rie "s/\\$pw = 'my_password'/\\$pw = \$new_pw/i;2i include('passwords.php');" {}
```